# adding pdf form field

Tags: language-agnostic

Using iTextSharp to add form fields to pdf files, then saving them as new files. This works, but it is fiddly to have to get the location and size of each form field.

Currently, I use trial and error to get the location and size right - is there a smarter way of doing this ? Or is there some (preferably free) PDF tool out there which will allow me to drag & drop form fields to existing pdf documents, and save them as new documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only tool that I'm aware of is [Adobe Acrobat Professional](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro.html).